# как сделать обводку combobox растягивающейся

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

есть border внутри которого combobox с кастомным стилем

border with combobox

```
 <Border  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="173 px" Height="23 px" BorderThickness="2"  BorderBrush="#454545" Background="#1c1c1c" CornerRadius="5">
                <ComboBox Style="{StaticResource CustomCombobox}"  Foreground="#717171">
                    <ComboBoxItem>No Device Selected</ComboBoxItem>
                </ComboBox>
```

оригинальный combobox

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как сделать так?

Изм. combobox
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

кастомный стиль

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="NormalBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Color="#1c1c1c" Offset="0.0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#1c1c1c" Offset="1.0"/>
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowBackgroundBrush" Color="#1c1c1c" />

        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="ToggleButton">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Border x:Name="Border" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" CornerRadius="2"
  Background="{StaticResource NormalBrush}"
  BorderThickness="1" />
                <Border 
  Grid.Column="0"
  CornerRadius="2,0,0,2" 
  Margin="1" 
  Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}" 
  BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" />
                <Path 
  x:Name="Arrow"
  Grid.Column="1"     
  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
  VerticalAlignment="Center"
  Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>

        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
            <Border x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
        </ControlTemplate>


        <Style x:Key="CustomCombobox" TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Grid>
                            <ToggleButton 
         Name="ToggleButton" 
         Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" 
         Grid.Column="2" 
         Focusable="false"
         IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
         ClickMode="Press">
                            </ToggleButton>
                            <ContentPresenter
        Name="ContentSite"
        IsHitTestVisible="False" 
        Margin="3,3,23,3"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                            <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
         Style="{x:Null}" 
         Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}" 
         HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
         VerticalAlignment="Center" 
         Margin="3,3,23,3"
         Focusable="True" 
         Background="Transparent"
         Visibility="Hidden"
         IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"/>
                            <Popup 
        Name="Popup"
        Placement="Bottom"
        IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
        AllowsTransparency="True" 
        Focusable="False"
        PopupAnimation="Slide">
                                <Grid 
          Name="DropDown"
          SnapsToDevicePixels="True"                
          MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
          MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                                    <Border 
            x:Name="DropDownBorder"
            Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"
            BorderThickness="1"/>
                                    <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                                    </ScrollViewer>
                                </Grid>
                            </Popup>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

стиль был взят остюда https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22695145/wpf-change-background-color-of-a-combobox

Comment: Ничего не понял, куда растягивать, зачем, почему... Вообще, по умолчанию в WPF **все** растягивается и подстраивается под размеры родителя/контента. Не задавайте размеры (`Width="173 px" Height="23 px"`), научитесь позиционировать обхекты и будет вам счастье.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я просто хочу чтобы обводка была на весь combobox вне зависимости от количества items. такие размеры я поставил потому что в дизайне который мне скинули уже есть размеры для этого dropdown элемента.